# Installing package in R with dependent packages in non-default location

Tags: r, install.packages

I'm trying to install the tiff package in a research computing environment via ssh without root access. The tiff package is dependent on the TIFF4 distribution which is not available on the research OS. I was able to build my own TIFF4 distribution locally, but install.packages("tiff") still searches in the default folder for the required files and the installation fails. I have no idea how to configure the installation to redirect it to the adhoc TIFF4 distribution under a local folder. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post any relevant local configuration files or directives?

Comment: It looks like that the installation is specifically looking for "tiff.h" and "tiffio.h", which are under local folder [user folder]/usr/local/include but R is only looking for them under the default root path.

Comment: you need to add details, error messages etc... Which file is not found, library or header files ?

Comment: ** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/curc/tools/x_86_64/rh6/R/3.0.2/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c common.c -o common.o
In file included from common.c:1:0:
common.h:5:18: fatal error: tiff.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [common.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tiff’